# How to enable Magento modules from the database access?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have accidentally disabled all of the modules from **System>Configuration>Advanced**. Now I can't access to my site or the admin panel. Both of them display a blank page. After that, I have found the database file from phymyadmin and run the following query:

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/%'
```

But no luck. My site as well as the Admin panel is still blank. Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: check core resource table if you want to add or upgarde , and update core_config_data and put disable_output/% to 0

Comment: What should I check there? Can you please be specific? I am a newbie in Magento

Comment: Please Check Following file : App->etc->module->mage_All.xml. set <active>true</active> for all module

Comment: I have already tried that before. It won't enable the module until we enable it from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check the core_config_data table in your database:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "advanced/modules_disable_output/%"
```

I guess there will be "1" in the "value" column. Change it to "0" for modules you want to be enabled. Then you'll probably need to clear caches - not sure if you can do it via backend but you can still delete files under your var/cache folder if you are using file cache storage.

Comment: I described on my problem that I can't access my Admin panel. It's completely blank. So, there 's no way to enable the modules from Admin panel

Comment: go for edited answer

Comment: I have so many folders under var/cache. Approx. 16 folders. Should I delete them all for clearing the cache?

Comment: ya you can delete all the folders

Comment: is it solve your problem?

Comment: Oh...Thanks a lot. After deleting the cache, site came back to live. Thank you. Can't upvote you coz my reputation point is below 15, don't mind.

Comment: always welcome bro